# RegEx for 2 decimal points including zeros

Tags: regex

I want an input field with a decimal number upto 2 decimals after the point.

I am using

```
^\d+\.\d{0,2}$
```

which works just fine with any 2 decimal number after the point but it does not consider two zeros i.e. 2.00.

How can I include 2.11 and as well as 2.00?

Comment: Can't reproduce. `2.00` is perfectly matched by the regex. (It does also match `2.0` or `2.`, not sure if that is desired)

Comment: I suspect you're trying to match what 2.00 rounds to ("2"), which has no decimal point.

Comment: You might want to make the fraction optional, `^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$` to allow integers.

Comment: @thg435 I made the group non-capturing and made a digit required if a decimal is present: `^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`